# samtools and seqkit installation failed with conda (bioconda)

Tags: conda, bioinformatics, samtools, bioconda

Using macOS Sonoma 14.1, and I've tried to install samtools and seqkit by bioconda, examples for samtools input and output are as follows, and for seqkit are the same.

command:
conda install -c bioconda samtools

return:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- samtools

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Also I do checked anaconda.org, and even follows the command in there:
conda install bioconda::samtools

and same fail happens. and OS seems capable too.

I've tried
conda install -c bioconda samtools
conda install samtools
none of them works.

Comment: In addition to using **osx-64** subdir, please note that one should never use merely `-c bioconda`. Bioconda *requires* Conda Forge be higher priority, so one must use `-c conda-forge -c bioconda`. Better, use YAMLs to define environments.